# How to execute class decorator first

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I have two decorators one that gets placed on a class and one that gets placed on a method. I am confused by the execution order. Why does the method decorator get called before the class decorator? Is there anyway to change this?

```
function ClassDecorator() {
  return (target: any): void => {
    console.log('Class decorator')
  }
}

function MethodDecorator() {
  return (target: any, method: string): void => {
    console.log('Method decorator: ' + method)
  }
}

@ClassDecorator()
class A {

    @MethodDecorator()
    public method() {

    }

}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAYQDYEMDOmAiBTCOAJ3SmIAoBKRAbwFgAoRRIvKEIpcqdIgczYAuROjABPSsIBucGABNEAXgB8tRs2aEwmOKjwA6VHD7kA5GiyZEcgsVLFTldYgC%20jNw0ahIsBIgCybAAWcHL4hCRkRFRqTCxsHFw8-EIi4gA0iAC2waHCmFBEMGB8kogy8kqq9HGaCDp6hsZmgVAhCjYR9kTCpogA1Nm5ck5xHh6MAAIW2OF2UVSMEBjYiACCsc7Mk63tc5EUoxqIAA4gAEaoMBBDbaExNVuujO5AA)

---

### My Specific Issue

I have a master class called `App` within that class there is an array which has references to my classes. I cannot get an existing class within that array from my method decorator because it is executing before the class decorator even has added that class to the array. Also there are some values that the method decorator needs from the parent decorator. Such as a root http path, because the method decorator can extend that path.

For example: `@ClassDecorator('/home')` and `@MethodDecorator('/profile')` should add a route `/home/profile`, but I am getting two array items one with `home` and one with `profile` because the decorators are running in the order that they are.

```
export class App {
  private readonly routes: Route[] = []

  // Called by the class decorator  
  public addController(controller: new () => any, url: string): void {
    let route = this.routes.find(route => route.controller instanceof controller)
    if (!route) {
      route = new Route()
      this.routes.push(route)
    }
    route.controller = controller
    route.rootPath = url
  }

  // Called by the method decorator
  public addRouteMethod(controller: new () => any, method: Method, url: string, command: string): void {
    let route = this.routes.find(route => route.controller instanceof controller)
    if (!route) {
      route = new Route()
      this.routes.push(route)
    }
    route.controller = controller
    route.commands.push(new Command({
      controller,
      command,
      method,
      path: path.posix.join(route.rootPath, url)
    }))
  }
}
```

Once I run my application I have an array of two items, when it should in fact be an array with one item where the second item is a child of the first item. I do know how I can fix this, but I would like the class decorator to execute first any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there's no way to change that. The method decorator is called when the method definition is completed, the class decorator is called when the entire class definition is completed.

Comment: The solution would be to only add metadata (such as creating `Route` instances) in the decorators, then registering these afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The [TypeScript decorator documentation specifies the order](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

1. Parameter Decorators, followed by Method, Accessor, or Property Decorators are applied for each instance member.
2. Parameter Decorators, followed by Method, Accessor, or Property Decorators are applied for each static member.
3. Parameter Decorators are applied for the constructor.
4. Class Decorators are applied for the class

But all evaluations are done before each call (as per the docs). Could you use that to do the class work in the evaluation step and the method work in the call step?